# function that returns an array of integers in random order

Tags: .net, arrays, function, random, integer

I need to write a function that returns an array of integers with 1000 elements containing the values 1 to 1000 in random order. with No omitted or repeated number.

so far I have:

```
private static void RandomNum()
    {
        //Initialize an array
        int[] randomList = new int[1000];
        //Initialize an instance of random class
        Random rnd = new Random();
        // integer variable
        int counter = 0;





            while (counter < 1000)
            {
                //store random num 
                int random = rnd.Next(1, 1001);


                if (Array.IndexOf(randomList, random) <= 0)
                {
                    //store random number into Array
                    randomList[counter] = random;
                    counter++;
                }




            }


        //output elements in Array
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(randomList[i]);
        }
        //output number of elements in Array
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: This is called a Shuffle. Algorithms can be found on Wikipedia.

Comment: so far I have:

Random rnd=new Random(); string[] MyRandomArray = MyArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next(1,1000)).ToArray();

Comment: So what's the remaining question? But also look for an in-place algorith (Yates).

Comment: "my answer should show good programming style, technique and attention to accuracy and performance" - sorry but seems like an interview or homeworkjob. Should your answer include then support from StackOverflow?

Comment: "dont want to use other .Net framework classes outside of the intrinsic data types (i.e. do not want to use collections)" - this seems to be contradictory, collections are "intrinsic" .NET fata types.

Answer (score 0):

// Psuedocode

```
HashSet<int> uniqueValues = new HashSet<int>();
while(uniqueValues.Count < 1000)
{
    uniqueValues.Add(Random.Next(1,1001));
}
```